# Artihmetical operations with json elements in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, subtraction

I try to make some operations with JSON files.

For example I intend to subtract them. But the problem is there can be different key elements.

```
         $a1=[
            {"cat":2,"total":1},
            {"cat":11,"total":23},
            {"cat":13,"total":30}
        ];

        $a2=[
            {"cat":2,"total":15},
            {"cat":11,"total":13},
            {"cat":15,"total":70},
            {"cat":16,"total":40}
        ];
```

and result must be

```
        $result=[
            {"cat":2,"total":14},
            {"cat":11,"total":-10},
            {"cat":13,"total":-30},
            {"cat":15,"total":70},
            {"cat":16,"total":40}
        ]
```

I have tried to take elements in a loop but I could not.

would you please show me the way to make this work ?

Comment: Add what you have tried to your question, and what errors you encountered.

Comment: i could not make it work.  i could not access json elements in the array

Comment: So your issue is about input and parsing. adapt your question accordingly and add all details like, your code, dump results, errors when trying to access elements, etc.... read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code:

```
<?php

$json1 = '[{"cat":2,"total":1},{"cat":11,"total":23},{"cat":13,"total":30}]';
$json2 = '[{"cat":2,"total":15},{"cat":11,"total":13},{"cat":15,"total":70},{"cat":16,"total":40}]';

$first = json_decode($json1, true);
$second = json_decode($json2, true);

$difference = [];

foreach ($second as $s) {
    $key = null;
    $f = array_filter($first, function($v, $k) use ($s, &$key){
        $result = $v["cat"] === $s["cat"];
        if ($result) $key = $k;
        return $result;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
    $total = $s["total"] - (count($f) ? $f[$key]["total"] : 0);
    $difference[]=["cat" => $s["cat"], "total" => $total];
}

foreach ($first as $f) {
    $s = array_filter($second, function($v, $k) use ($f) {
        return $v["cat"] === $f["cat"];
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
    if (!count($s)) {
        $difference[]=["cat" => $f["cat"], $total => -$f["total"]];
    }
}

echo var_dump($difference); //I tested by echoing it out
```

Explanation:

- I initialize two variables with the JSON inputs you have defined
- I decode them both using `json_decode` and I set the second parameter to `true` to make sure they will be associative arrays
- I loop the second

  - I initialize the key with null
  - I search for a match in the first using `$s` and `$key` so I will see these variables in the closure of the function

    - If I find such a match then I initialize `$key` with it
  - I subtract the first total (if exists) from the total
  - I add a new item with the matching category and the correct new total
- I loop the first

  - I search a match in the second using `$f`
- If no matches were found, I add the item with the matching category and negative total

In short, I loop the second and subtract the matching first if they exist, defaulting to 0 and then I loop the first to add the elements that do not have a match in the second.

[image]

Comment: it works like a charm. thank you. i have learned a lot with these codes. Your answer is pretty self explanatory.